# Completely waterproof top of deck/shed (would TigerPaw work?)

Tags: deck, waterproofing, roofing, shed

I have a deck at my front door. I have made it so that below the deck is a shed. I am having trouble water proofing the top of the deck. I have seen many things on the internet to have something under the deck boards to move water to the outside of the shed. The deck isn't high enough for me to do that. I also cannot put plywood on top of the deck because it would then be higher than the metal at the bottom of the front door and would trap water there.

I was thinking of filling in the space between the 2 x 6's with a caulk, then placing [Tiger Paw](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Unbranded-400-sq-ft-Tiger-Paw-Roof-Deck-Protection-0983/203225516) on the deck. Then after that use [Deck Over](http://www.homedepot.com/p/BEHR-Premium-DeckOver-1-gal-Wood-and-Concrete-Coating-500001/206031374) to paint over the top of it.

I have a few concerns with this and was wondering what others thought. The TigerPaw is $80 and each gallon of deck over is $30. Being on a tight budget I want to make sure its a sound idea before I spend that money.

1. Would the Tiger Paw get ripped easily? I'll have the caulk in between the boards and the screw holes filled so that there will not be any weak points.
2. Will the Deck Over paint be slippery when it snows? Should I get some sort of texture spray or something just to be safe? (I have a dog, so it can't be that rough)
3. Is this solution going to last a while or will I have to replace it every couple years?

This is my first home, and I am not too experienced with roofing. It's not that big of a deck (4'x 10') so it's not something I want to hire someone for. More importantly, I am on a tight budget. I already have the walls and everything else built, this is the last step. My original idea failed.

Is this a acceptable solution? Or are there any better suggestions out there?

Comment: Guaranteed leakage. Deck boards move with temperature changes.

Comment: Better off building a roof under the deck that sheds water and leaving the spaces between the boards alone. I've seen this done with a metal roof under a deck.

Comment: I don't really have much space to build a roof under the deck.